# OpenTBS / PHP - How do I dynamically generate horizontal values for embedded graph inside of docx template?

Tags: php, opentbs

I have a graph for which I was able to manually create x axis values in a docx template.  The template outputs the correct graph.   Instead of relying upon manually entering all x values and substituting the values from the php array, I want to dynamically populate the horizontal axis with values from a php array.

**PHP Code**

```
// --------------------------------------------
        // Merging and other operations on the template
        // --------------------------------------------
        // Change chart series
        $ChartNameOrNum = 'Buildup'; // Title of the shape that embeds the chart
        $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 1';
        $NewValues = array($buildupLabels['TotalActionItems'], $buildupSeries['TotalActionItems'] );
        $NewLegend = "Total Action Items";
        $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

        // Delete comments
        $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_COMMENTS);
```

**Output File with Rendered Chart**

[image: Output Chart]

**Chart Template**

[image: BuildUp Template]

**Table of x-axis values**

[image: Manually Entered Values]

How can I achieve the above?  Is this possible using the OpenTBS, or do I need to manually enter all x axis values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that I do not need to automatically generate all of the horizontal values in the embedded chart. All I need to do is put one date in the first record (e.g. Mar 05 15 or anything else not even in the range of dates I am populating) and the series will automatically populate all available dates from my PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTBS enables you to change x and y values for any of the series.
So you just have to change all (x,y) items for all of your series then old x values should totally disappear in your chart. You have to get an automatic min and max for the x axis in order to have it adapted to the new values.

You also have to keep in mind the Ms Office Charts behavior :

- If your chart type is a XY (also named Scatter), then (x,y) of your series entries can be in any order, and the x axis will not necessary display values used by items. This is nice when you have several series with different x values and you want to display unused x values in the x axe.
- If your chart type different from a XY then x values are considered as categories. Only used values will be displayed in the x axis. If tow series have different categories all possible values are displayed in the x axis.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I was wondering if I need to change the x values, that I need modified,inside the embedded excel file and replace them with the OpenTBS tags, or do I change them inside the PHP script?   I am using a line chart option in my doc file.

Comment: You only need to use the `OPENTBS_CHART` command with OpenTBS at the PHP side. You cannot actually change the values embedded in the Excel file: it's is a true XLSX document, complicated to unzip and to read data. And most of all, this XLSX file is used only for facilitating the edition thought Ms Office, its is not the true data of the chart. OpenTBS changes only the true data of the chart.